# How to switch between screens using react navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created 3 components. 1) Login screen 2)VenueList screen 3) Menu Screen
I have created another component called as AuthLoading this component navigates user from Login screen to VenueList screen. AuthLoading is bridge component which connects pre login and post login components.

Login screen has a button which onclick will fire loginAction.js and user is navigated to web browser where he enters email/password.  After receiving the accessToken user must be navigated to VenueList screen but switchNavigator is not working. How can I implement it ?

Login.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loginUser } from '../actions/loginAction';

class Login extends Component {

  _signInAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('accessToken', this.props.accessToken);
    this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
  }

  render() {

    console.log(this.props.accessToken);

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button
        onPress={this.props.loginUser}
        title="Click to Login"
        ></Button>
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

loginAction.js:

```
import { LOGIN_USER } from './types';
import Auth0 from 'react-native-auth0';

var credentials = require('./auth0-credentials');
const auth0 = new Auth0(credentials);

export const loginUser = () => dispatch => {

    auth0.webAuth
    .authorize({
      scope: 'openid profile',
      audience: 'https://' + credentials.domain + '/userinfo'
    })
    .then(credentials => 

        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_USER,
            payload: credentials.accessToken
        })
    )
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
    
};
```

authLoading.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, ActivityIndicator, AsyncStorage, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

export default class AuthLoading extends Component {
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._bootstrapAsync();
  }

  _bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    const accessToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('accessToken');

    // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
    // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
    this.props.navigation.navigate(accessToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');
  };

  render() {
    
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ActivityIndicator />
            <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
        </View>
    );
  }

}
```

app.js:

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ Venues: VenueList, Menu: ItemsMenu });
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ Login: Login });

const AppStackNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
);
```

Screenshot:

[image]

In above screenshot after receiving accessToken user is navigated back again to login screen but instead of that I want to navigate user to VenueList screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `accessToken` is set at the start of render function in `Login` component and navigate the user to `VenueList` screen if logged in.

```
class Login extends Component {

  _signInAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('accessToken', this.props.accessToken);
    this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
  }

  render() {
    if(this.props.accessToken) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('VenueList')
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button
        onPress={this.props.loginUser}
        title="Click to Login"
        ></Button>
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: `_signInAsync` is never getting called ? Also when user clicks loginUser action is fired and in web browser the user enters email and password after that he is navigated back to login screen with accessToken.

Comment: If you are using redux, you shouldn't set `accessToken` in `_signInAsync`. you can add a field for `accessToken` inside the reducer, and set `accessToken` in `LOGIN_USER` action of the reducer.

Comment: I am using redux with redux thunk middleware. I want to ask you should I add `_signInasync` inside loginUser action i.e loginAction ? But if I add there then how can I set item in asyncstorage in loginAction.js See my edited question.

Comment: Thanks buddy your code works like a charm :) I just want to ask you how can I persist data by saving accessToken in asyncStorage by using loginAction.js

Comment: You can use redux-persist to save your redux state. it automatically saves and loads all the redux state from Storage when you start the app. the usage is so simple https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

Answer (score 1):

You should not navigate in render. Do it in `componentDidMount()` or `componetDidUpdate()`

```
class Login extends Component {

  _signInAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('accessToken', this.props.accessToken);
    this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    if(this.props.accessToken) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('VenueList')
    }
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button
        onPress={this.props.loginUser}
        title="Click to Login"
        ></Button>
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```